# Testing iap levels

Tags: ios, testing, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, itunes

I am creating an app which use auto renewable subscriptions. Last time I notice that Apple changed the way in adding new products. Now we can add levels and our products can be upgrade or downgrade. How can I test this feature? I have sandbox account and in my iTunes account I can't see any subscriptions to manage and change levels of subscription.

Comment: It doesn't seem that you can test upgrade/downgrade in the sandbox. You need to ensure that your app handles subscriptions correctly; upgraded subscriptions should take effect immediately. Downgraded subscriptions take effect at the end of the current subscription period.

Comment: Actually upgrades work in sandbox. There is one strange thing though that I'm not sure if it's intended or a bug - when upgrading, both previous lower level iap has expiration date in the future and the new higher level one as well with the correct time. So it's a bit confusing how to determine which one you should handle in the app as StoreKit doesn't provide any info about the levels, duration etc. I've implemented my own way to get such data as it's really important at least in my case. Downgrades don't seem to work and sometimes they just "cancel" previous iap.

Comment: Just a note - I just saw today that downgrades work as well as expected. I spent two days testing this and it wasn't working but today it just surprised me :)